# layout quirks switching between portrait/landscape

Tags: layout, position, landscape, portrait

I know this type of question has been asked many times before but I haven't found an answer to my specific issue yet so I thought i would post.

It's really a bit of a quirk I guess rather than anything else but I have designed a responsive site that resizes nicely in a browser when you resize the window and works perfectly when you load it up in either portrait or landscape on a mobile. However when you load it in portrait and then turn the mobile into landscape some mobile browsers don't load up the correct styling for the new screen size - BUT IT DOESN'T HAPPEN LIKE THIS FOR ALL BROWSERS! So far I have tested it on an Android 4.0.4 version phone using the standard Android browser and it resizes correctly when switching orientations but then on the same phone using google chrome as the browser it applies different styling BUT if you refresh the page it then applies the correct styling.

So my question is how can I force the mobile browser to render the page correctly on orientation change without having to reload the page?

The site in question is www.the-baobab.co.uk and im using the viewport meta tag and setting it to width=device-width and an initial scale of 1 then calling media queries at certain max pixel widths to alter positioning and layout for various different screen sizes which can be seen in my stylesheet1.css [here](http://smokescreenevents.co.uk/the-baobab/style/stylesheet1.css)